# Which is faster: foo.constructor === Constructor or foo.constructor.name === "Constructor"?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, constructor

I never knew which is faster: `foo.constructor === Constructor` or `foo.constructor.name === "Constructor"` (`foo` is not `null` or `undefined`)?

Let's take an example:

```
var obj = {};

if (obj.constructor === Object) {
     /* do something */
}

if (obj.constructor.name === "Object") {
     /* do something */
}
```

Which is faster?

I would prefer to use `obj.constructor === Object` just because it's shorter, but is there any reason for what I must use `obj.constructor.name === "Object"`? Is it faster than `obj.constructor === Object`?

Comment: Just test its speed by running a loop that performs this same thing a couple times. I did this for you, and here are the results for me:

`var obj = {};console.time("test1");for (var i=0;i<100000;i++) if (obj.constructor === Object) 1; else 0;console.timeEnd("test1");/* -> test1: 171.000ms*/   console.time("test2");for (var i=0;i<100000;i++) if (obj.constructor.name === "Object") 1; else 0;console.timeEnd("test2");/*test2: 143.000ms*/`

So the `obj.constructor.name` way is faster, but only by 28/100000 ms per computation. It's not really a big difference.

Comment: ^^ I would have posted that as an answer, but it was put on hold. It would have been a bit clearer as an answer with proper formatting.

Comment: Fun fact: These two aren't equivalent. Consider `var obj = new (function Object() {});`.

Comment: The first: http://pastebin.com/X0z6wZA6
Comparing string is always much more slower than comparing references, booleans or numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [the first one is faster](http://jsperf.com/class-comparison-vs-name-string-comparison) (link to jsperf), at least in Chrome 31. (The next time you have a performance question like this, JSPerf can be very helpful.)

This seems right, since you don't have to create a string in the first one, and comparing strings is naturally slower than comparing objects anyway.

However, this is really micro-optimization. Will a user *really* notice a difference? (No.) Use whatever you think is more readable.